# Why does Windows Explorer seem to hang when copying many files?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

I've been trying to manually back up about 200 Gb of music by transferring it -- drag and drop in Explorer -- from my hard drive to an external drive in Windows 7.

A few folders, no problem. Many folders... problem. I haven't nailed down a precise number, but it seems like every time I try to drag folders with over 10 Gb in contents total, Windows just... refuses. It doesn't do anything. No error messages, no nothin'. Just a complete lack of response.

If I try EXACTLY the same operation, but with only a few folders, it executes flawlessly. It's only when I'm trying to drag and drop a lot of stuff at once that it doesn't work.

Comment: I have transferred folders containing hundreds of GBs ( .5TB) without issue

Comment: Perhaps you could use extra copying software, such as [UltraCopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/), or [Copy Handler](http://www.copyhandler.com/) to help.

Comment: Can you do the exact same transfer successfully by breaking it into parts? This would eliminate most hardware issues. Can you do the full copy from a command line? You might see some error messages that are ignored in the gui. This would also narrow it down to the gui.